# How to use HockeyAppSDK with Qt on Android

Tags: android, qt, hockeyapp

We use Qt and HockeyApp on various platforms, including Android.  We make our deployment with the androiddeployqt tool.  We can't figure out how to use the most recent HockeySDK-Android-4.0.1.aar file.  In particular, the aar file includes various resources which seem to need to be merged with those from Qt, but we can't figure out the steps to do this.  The errors we get from missing symbols in the R.java file. The HockeyApp instructions all assume use of Android Studio IDE, which of course we don't use with Qt.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question related to the HockeySDK as much as support for AAR bundled libraries in Qt in general. So it's possibly a dupe [hereof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147640/using-aar-library-with-qt).
The [AAR format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) itself is pretty simple, but it seems there is no official support for AAR libraries in Qt.
Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of HockeySDK for Android.