# How to use HockeyApp SDK with Qt on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, hockeyapp

I am trying to integrate the [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net) Android SDK in its [latest version 4.1.2](https://hockeyapp.net/releases) into our Qt Android app. I don't know a lot about Android development or Java in general - nor any Qt or HockeyApp internals.

There is some general [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android3rdpartylibs.html#including-the-library-in-the-source) on including third party Android (i.e. Java) libraries into a Qt project; however, it mentions a "*Create AndroidManifest.xml* button in the Deployment settings" which does not exist in the current Qt Creator 4.2.0 version, so I am unsure as to how outdated this documentation is or what parts possibly still apply.

[HockeyApp documentation](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk) only covers "typical Android development" using Android Studio and their support is [not supportive](https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/56465-using-hockeysdk-with-qt-on-android).

On a side note, integrating the HockeyApp *iOS* SDK took just a couple of hours and was mostly a matter of writing some Objective C bridge code.

### Step 1: Add the SDK to the project

#### First approach

I tried to follow the above documentation and added the unzipped `HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2` folder and a `project.properties` file with contents

```
android.library.reference.1=HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs/
```

to a project folder; I also set [ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#android-specific-qmake-variables) in `<my project>.pro` to that project folder.

**Problem**: The `androiddeployqt` build step issues an error message (wrapped for readability)

```
Error: <path to build folder>/android-build/HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs
  is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found).
```

but continues anyway and finally fails with an error message (also wrapped for readability)

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:573:
  HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs/ resolve to a path
  with no project.properties file for project <path to build folder>/android-build
```

Running `androiddeployqt` with a `--verbose` switch adds significantly more output, but zero useful information.

---

#### Second approach

The downloaded HockeyApp Android SDK zip archive contains - besides some documentation - a file `libs/HockeySDK-4.1.2.aar`; from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207053) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100951/how-to-use-hockeyappsdk-with-qt-on-android#comment61763248_37100951), I gather the [AAR format](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents) is simply a zip archive that, among others, contains an `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I unzipped `libs/HockeySDK-4.1.2.aar` in place, then removed it; now the first error message in the build is gone.

**Problem**: The build fails with

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:597:
  The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:649:
  The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:655:
  <path to build folder>/android-build/HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs/src does not exist.
```

Again, adding running `--verbose` to `androiddeployqt` adds nothing but noise. Looking into the `build.xml` locations mentioned doesn't help either.

**Update:**

I tried simply creating the missing folder from the error message; now the build fails as follows:

```
-dex:
      [dex] input: <path to build folder>/android-build/bin/classes
      [dex] input: <path to build folder>/android-build/HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs/bin/classes.jar
      [dex] input: <path to build folder>/android-build/libs/QtAndroid-bundled.jar
      [dex] input: <path to build folder>/android-build/libs/QtAndroidBearer-bundled.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing <path to build folder>/android-build/libs/QtAndroid-bundled.jar -> QtAndroid-bundled-a06280f40655c27b25038380a4d7f67c.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing <path to build folder>/android-build/libs/QtAndroidBearer-bundled.jar -> QtAndroidBearer-bundled-a69fa323dbfa477411ea082423128813.jar
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into <path to build folder>/android-build/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx]
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.io.FileNotFoundException: <path to build folder>/android-build/HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs/bin/classes.jar (No such file or directory)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
       [dx]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
       [dx] 1 error; aborting

BUILD FAILED
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:283: null returned: 1
```

I obviously can not just make up some `classes.jar` file, but there is one single file with that name in `<path to build folder>/android-build/HockeySDK-Android-4.1.2/libs`, so I can create the missing `bin` folder and create a symlink in it to `../classes.jar`.

The build now succeeds. Step 1 complete.

### Step 2: Use the SDK in the project

Going back to the corresponding [HockeyApp documentation](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#modify-code), I gather I need to modify some code that looks similar to

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
  ...
```

There is one single occurrence of such code in the project in `<path to build folder>/android-build/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity.java`:

```
public class QtActivity extends Activity
  ...
```

That file is copied there by the [`androiddeployqt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#androiddeployqt) tool (part of the Qt SDK) from its source folder inside the Qt SDK at `$QTDIR/src/android/java`, i.e. `/opt/Qt/Qt_5.7.1/5.7/android_armv7/src/android` on my machine.

Looking at the `androiddeployqt` source code, I see there is no way (e.g. by means of a command line parameter) to change the source folder these `.java` files are taken from, so it is not possible to provide my own set of files and have `androiddeployqt` copy that instead. Hence, in order to make this work, I must either extend / fix `androiddeployqt` functionality (sorry, I won't touch that code - yuck!) or modify the copied files at their source directly - which then obviously affects all projects build with that Qt SDK instance.

As a third approach, I could try patching the Java sources *after* `androiddeployqt` copied them to the build folder. Unfortunately, this not only makes the development and build workflow absurdly painful; it is also made entirely impossible by the `androiddeployqt` "one tool does everything" design fail (see below): There is no point in time in the build process where the Java sources exist in the project and the `.apk` package has not been built yet. I thought the `androiddeployqt` `--no-build` parameter would enable that:

```
--no-build: Do not build the package, it is useful to just install
   a package previously built.
```

but "building" here refers to building the Qt / Java bridge code, not the actual app, so that parameter turns out to be pretty much useless for the task at hand; the build fails with this message - which by itself are a bug as the `.apk` file from the message does not exist and thus the Android package build was not successful:

```
Android package built successfully in 1.011 ms.
  -- File: <path to build folder>/android-build//bin/QtApp-release-unsigned.apk
```

Sure, I could copy the sources elsewhere, patch and copy them manually to their final destination, but I think this is where I draw the line.

Actually, looking at the `androiddeployqt` source code is where the buck stops. Too much time has already been wasted trying to get dysfunctional tools to work:

- I will not comment on how smart it is to write a *build tool* in *C++* in the first place - in a single, ~3000 line `main.cpp` file
- I will not comment on the practice of hardcoding the `src/android/java` path (and many other paths) in the `androiddeployqt` sources not *once*, but *multiple* times - instead of a `const QString` that at least *prepares* appropriate (i.e. external) tool configuration
- I will not comment on how smart it is to violate the ~50 year old best practice of *one tool, one purpose* - and duplicate large amounts of functionality provided by Qt, Android or Java tools, such as building, signing, deploying, installing packages, etc.
- However, the fact that this tool has made it past code review into a number of major Qt release is nothing short of frightening - and probably a good indicator that it's time to consider dropping Qt as a technology in general

While I am writing this, the Qt 5.8.0 installation keeps freezing, maxing out one CPU core - and has been doing so for the last ~12 hours. I rest my case.

#### My questions

- <s>has anyone had any success with Qt, Android and HockeyApp ?</s>
- <s>does anyone have any hints / pointers / wild guesses as to what is wrong here ?</s>
- no further questions; I've seen enough

### Step 3: Call SDK Java code from C++

(cancelled due to brickwall in step 2)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW this is an `AndroidManifest.xml` I use for an app, no external library dependencies though. You could try adding+modifying this to get the deploy to work?

File structure:

```
/my-project-dir
├── android
│   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   └── res
│       └── drawable-mdpi
│           └── icon.png
├── my-project.pro
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="my_package_name" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="my_app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="my_app_name" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->

            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!--
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/>
            -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default features based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default features. -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->

<!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
</manifest>
```

Comment: @ssc I didn't mind but removed it anyway, it will live on in your comment though ; ) As an aside: as a middle way you could create a new kit using QtCreator, e.g. android_armv7_hockey, and modify QtActivity.java there? Or call the java methods from C++, although that'll probably lead down another rabbit hole.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Your AndroidManifest.xml file seems to correspond to the one I have in my project, but in an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Using the HockeyApp SDK with Qt on Android is not possible without either patching Qt SDK tool source code or Qt SDK Java template source files.

In fact, from what I gather, it is not possible to use *any* third party libraries with Qt on Android if they require Java source code modification.